# how to make the osx-like border on css?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to do a border with css like this

[image: border]

what I have for now is something like this:

```
input,textarea,select {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-family: Monaco !important;
}

input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus,checkbox:focus,input[type=checkbox]:focus
    {
    border: 2px solid #8aade1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #8aade1;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #8aade1;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #8aade1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #8aade1;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;


    outline: none;
}

/* Desativar borda zuada no firefox */
input::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tNPmT/
Is there a way to make it more similar?

Comment: it looks pretty good, what are you upset with? the color? the corners?

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS transitions?

Comment: guess the color is not the same...ops, wrong tag :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work on some browsers...but not all. And it won't work on select elements in FF or IE. (I know. I tried it a week ago.) I know that Google does something similar, but when I tried looking at their code, they actually have the *appearance* of select elements, but they're not really that. I wussed out and just went with a simple outline instead of trying to get the exact same box-shadow.

Not what you want to hear, I know...but that's my experience.

Comment: I'm already using it on firefox and chrome...IE is not a problem for us

Comment: "IE is not a problem for us." Because you got it to work? Or because you're not supporting it? (My team is counting down until we can stop supporting IE6 in the purchase path. We're close...so close...but not there yet!! Ugh.) I had the worst time getting this to work on select elements in IE8 and even in Firefox - you're saying you got it to work? I'll have to give this a shot!

Comment: in our company, everyone SHOULD use chrome or firefox...TI guys install it by default...but we doesn't test on IE (yeah, shame on us)

Comment: ...I miss the days when I was supporting an intranet, instead of a consumer-facing site. Yes, we had to support IE; but we were able to lop off IE6 support in 2010. (Never mind me. Just mourning now.) BAck to your code - what about adding a blur number to the box-shadow? Are you looking for a wider radius, or a wider soft-border?

Comment: I made something like `box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px 2px #8aade1 !important;` but seems like the componens 'grows' and the border shows up

Comment: When you say the component"grows" are you talking about the displacement onFocus, when the border shows up? The way around that is to put a similar box-shadow on all your form elements, but make it the same color as the background. That way they'll all have it already, it will just be changing colors. For the :focus box-shadow styledef, try     box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #8aade1 #important;  and see if that looks like you want it to.

Comment: no...seems like the focused component pushs the components around him by, I don't know, 4px or something

Comment: We're saying the same thing, but using different words. You mean that when a component is focussed, it kind of "jumps" a 4px down (2px for the top part of the box shadow, 2px for the bottom part.) That's because the :focussed element suddenly gets that box-shadow. If you have a grey background, add a grey box-shadow to all of your form elements, with the same dimensions as the :focus box-shadow - just a different color. Then, when you focus on a form field, it won't "jump" - just display the blue box-shadow.